# numpy: Resize 3d array with interpolation in 2d

Tags: python, numpy

I've a numpy array with the shape `(NUMBER_IMAGES,IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT)`

I now want to downsize this array to `(NUMBER_IMAGES,NEW_IMAGE_WIDTH,NEW_IMAGE_HEIGHT)` in the most efficient way. However, I want that the interpolation (e.g BILINEAR) is only applied on per image.

Right I'm looping over the first dimension and downsize + interpolate per image with PIL. 
'''

```
    for i in range(len(images)):
        img_tmp = images[i, :, :]
        img_tmp = np.array(Image.fromarray(img_tmp).resize((NEW_SIZE, NEW_SIZE), resample=Image.BILINEAR))
        if resized_array is None:
            resized_array = np.empty(
                shape=(images.shape[0], img_tmp.shape[0], img_tmp.shape[1])
            )
        resized_array[i, :, :] = img_tmp
```

But I guess there is a more efficient way.

Any ideas?

Comment: The data of one slice is independent of the data of another slice, so I would guess that a loop is already close to the most efficient way. However you could dig into the internals of the interpolation and see what stuff that is independent of the image data they compute (weights,...) and then instead of recalculating this, store it and reuse it. May speed up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with [`scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation

def resize_batch(image_batch, new_width, new_height):
    image_batch = np.asarray(image_batch)
    shape = list(image_batch.shape)
    shape[1] = new_width
    shape[2] = new_height
    ind = np.indices(shape, dtype=float)
    ind[1] *= (image_batch.shape[1] - 1) / float(new_width - 1)
    ind[2] *= (image_batch.shape[2] - 1) / float(new_height - 1)
    return scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates(image_batch, ind, order=1)

print(resize_batch(np.zeros([10, 20, 30]), 60, 15).shape)
# (10, 60, 15)

print(resize_batch(np.zeros([10, 20, 30, 3]), 60, 15).shape)
# (10, 60, 15, 3)
```

EDIT:

Here are a couple of other versions. This one uses only NumPy operations without SciPy, computing bilinear interpolation "by hand":

```
import numpy as np

def resize_batch_np(image_batch, new_width, new_height):
    dtype = image_batch.dtype
    n, width, height = image_batch.shape[:3]
    extra_dims = image_batch.ndim - 3
    w = np.linspace(0, width - 1, new_width, dtype=dtype)[:, np.newaxis]
    h = np.linspace(0, height - 1, new_height, dtype=dtype)
    nn = np.arange(n, dtype=np.int32)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    ii_1 = w.astype(np.int32)
    ii_2 = (ii_1 + 1).clip(max=width - 1)
    w_alpha = w - ii_1
    w_alpha = w_alpha.reshape(w_alpha.shape + (1,) * extra_dims)
    w_alpha_1 = 1 - (w_alpha)
    jj_1 = h.astype(np.int32)
    jj_2 = (jj_1 + 1).clip(max=height - 1)
    h_alpha = h - jj_1
    h_alpha = h_alpha.reshape(h_alpha.shape + (1,) * extra_dims)
    h_alpha_1 = 1 - (h_alpha)
    out_11 = image_batch[nn, ii_1, jj_1]
    out_12 = image_batch[nn, ii_1, jj_2]
    out_21 = image_batch[nn, ii_2, jj_1]
    out_22 = image_batch[nn, ii_2, jj_2]
    return ((out_11 * h_alpha_1 + out_12 * h_alpha) * w_alpha_1 +
            (out_21 * h_alpha_1 + out_22 * h_alpha) * w_alpha)
```

And this other one does the same but with Numba:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def resize_batch_nb(image_batch, new_width, new_height):
    dtype = image_batch.dtype
    n, width, height = image_batch.shape[:3]
    extra_dims = image_batch.ndim - 3
    w = np.empty(new_width, dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(new_width):
        w[i] = (width - 1) * i / (new_width - 1)
    h = np.empty(new_height, dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(new_height):
        h[i] = (height - 1) * i / (new_height - 1)
    ii_1 = w.astype(np.int32)
    ii_2 = np.minimum(ii_1 + 1, width - 1)
    w_alpha = w - ii_1
    w_alpha_1 = 1 - (w_alpha)
    jj_1 = h.astype(np.int32)
    jj_2 = np.minimum(jj_1 + 1, height - 1)
    h_alpha = h - jj_1
    h_alpha_1 = 1 - (h_alpha)
    out = np.empty((n, new_width, new_height) + image_batch.shape[3:], dtype=dtype)
    for idx in nb.prange(n):
        for i in nb.prange(new_width):
            for j in nb.prange(new_height):
                out_11 = image_batch[idx, ii_1[i], jj_1[j]]
                out_12 = image_batch[idx, ii_1[i], jj_2[j]]
                out_21 = image_batch[idx, ii_2[i], jj_1[j]]
                out_22 = image_batch[idx, ii_2[i], jj_2[j]]
                out_1 = out_11 * h_alpha_1[j] + out_12 * h_alpha[j]
                out_2 = out_21 * h_alpha_1[j] + out_22 * h_alpha[j]
                out[idx, i, j] = out_1 * w_alpha_1[i] + out_2 * w_alpha[i]
    return out
```

The result is the same as before:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
image_batch = np.random.rand(100, 200, 300, 3).astype(float)
new_width = 60
new_height = 80
out = resize_batch(image_batch, new_width, new_height)
out_np = resize_batch_np(image_batch, new_width, new_height)
out_nb = resize_batch_nb(image_batch, new_width, new_height)
print(np.allclose(out, out_np))
# True
print(np.allclose(out, out_nb))
# True
```

But the performance improves significantly:

```
%timeit resize_batch(image_batch, new_width, new_height)
# 211 ms ± 9.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit resize_batch_np(image_batch, new_width, new_height)
# 106 ms ± 1.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit resize_batch_nb(image_batch, new_width, new_height)
# 48.3 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately it is slower :-(

Comment: @Thorsten I added a couple of other implementations that should run faster.

Comment: Amazing stuff! I tried it quickly and it is MUCH faster. Thanks a lot!